# Brightness control or toggle of backlight on ads7846 TFT touchscreen?

Tags: display, touchscreen, pitft

I have a 3.5" ads7846 based touchscreen for my Pi from Waveshare. Is it possible to toggle the backlight and/or change the brightness?

Comment: What do Waveshare say?